# Top 10 per unit in python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have delay data for 105 units. I need the data to show the Top 10 largest delays per unit.

I need it to show 3 columns `Unit, DelayDesc, and Time_hrs` and each unit needs to show only the top 10 `DelayDesc` and the hours for those 10 largest delays

**At the moment I can only get each unit separated by all its delays using this python code:**

```py
Duration_Hr = df['Duration_s']/3600 # calulation from seconds to hours

df['Duration_Hr'] = Duration_Hr  # adding Duration_Hr to the dataframe (df)

Sum_Time =df.groupby(['Unit','DelayDesc'])['Duration_Hr'].sum().to_frame('Time_Hrs')
print(Sum_Time)
```

**with output:**

[output of code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy7oy.jpg)

What am I missing? What don't I know? please explain simply. I have only been using python for a couple months now and everything is quite confusing so hopefully this question makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not having your exact data to test with, I can't be positive, but it may be as simple as using the pandas function for [`df.nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html).

If your `Sum_Time` dataframe has the correct data but the last question is to just get the top 10 by `['Time_Hrs'], this should do it.

```py
df_final = Sum_Time.nlargest(10,'Time_Hrs')
print(df_final)
```